# SQL Query not querying properly. not sure what wrong

Tags: mysql, sql

Basic thing, I have a simple SQL query I'm trying to run but it doesn't work. the issue i've found is this:

```
hour(NOW()) >= start_hour
```

and the original code is this:

```
SELECT * FROM shows WHERE hour(NOW()) >= start_hour 
AND hour(NOW()) < end_hour AND WEEKDAY(NOW()) = day
```

Some sample data

> ID    ---NAME -------- SHOW  -------------- IMAGE-- DAY-Start_time - 
>   End_time
>
> 1 - Shea Lavington - Morning Show! - Chris.png - 0 - 06:00:00 - 10:00:00

```
ID  int
presenter   text
show    text
image   text
day decimal
start_hour  time
end_hour    time
```

Comment: Quote: "I have a simple SQL query I'm trying to run but it doesn't work."

Comment: Ok so it doesn't work in what sense? That's what the comment meant. Do you get any errors? What happens?

Comment: what you want? because as i see this is fine

Comment: The query is returning no responses, however upon removal of "hour(NOW()) >= start_hour" it works fine.

Comment: what is the value of day in your table. is it string ?

Comment: What is the field type for start_hour and what value does it contain? Can you provide some sample data

Comment: the issue is not day. the issue is start_hour. but I'm unsure why, but day is numeric, and start/end time is "time"

Comment: provide some sample data

Comment: Just post the table definition and the data in your table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the issue is not day. the issue is start_hour. but I'm unsure why, but day is numeric, and start/end time is "time"

Simple! That means you are comparing  `6` with `06:00:00`. Simply apply HOUR to both sides and not just one, so you get a number on both sides to compare.

```
hour(NOW()) >= HOUR(start_hour)
```

Like this

```
SELECT * FROM shows 
WHERE WEEKDAY(NOW()) = day
AND HOUR(NOW()) BETWEEN HOUR(start_hour) AND HOUR(end_hour)
```

Might as well get rid of all this `HOUR` stuff

```
SELECT * FROM shows 
WHERE WEEKDAY(NOW()) = day
AND NOW() BETWEEN start_hour AND end_hour
```

Answer (score 0):

what you need is not Now() for hour try CURTIME() for hour() and CURDATE() for weekday() so make it like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM shows 
WHERE hour(CURTIME()) >= hour(start_hour) 
  AND hour(CURTIME()) < hour(end_hour)
  AND WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) = day
```

Comment: Not working. the issue seems to be here

hour(CURTIME()) >= start_hour 

I think it's the >= but I'm unsure why

Comment: @SheaLavington since you just update the information that your start_hour is time type then this is the problem, you hour() the time then you got a numeric. you have to hour your start hour too.

Comment: @SheaLavington and i have to make sure of this otherwise someone will down vote me again. is the data for start_hour/end_hour save in time and formed like '00:00:00'this? or just '00' if it's '00' please convert it to numeric

Comment: Yeah, that's it, now() works just the same but thanks :D the problem was hour() on both